# find value from third cell when entered value is between one and two cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have made this table:

```
          A    |     B   |    C  
     ----------|---------|---------- 
           1   |   100   |    50
         101   |   200   |    75
         201   |   300   |   100


*A = km
*B = km
*C = rs
```

I would like to extract value from `C` when users entered a value, within the range of `A` and `B`

Example:

```
          D    |    E   
     ----------|---------
         105   |    75   

 *D = user manual entry
 *E = result
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Stop yelling.  And your formatting isn't intuitively suggesting what are in the cells you're referencing.

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula in E1:

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$C$3,3)
```

Comment: +1 for the approach but if D1 = 105 won't that return 50? Think you need to use col A as lookup range, i.e. `=VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$C$3,3)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment - of course you're right. I edited the answer.

Comment: Dont know what happened - that's what I wanted to do. Done now! :-)

Comment: +1. That should work in all the reasonable edge cases. (Although, amusingly, it's possible to have D1 return 50 by entering 100.999999999999, calculating correctly but with E1 displaying 101.)